# can we cache count query before request hits django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have home page which lists from a very large table. It is paginated by **PageNumberPagination**. The loading time of this page is affected because of the `count(*)` query of the paginator. I resolved slowness for all other requests by installing **django-cachalot**. However the first request still takes up a lot of time. I tried to create a fake request in `AppConfig.ready()` so that the `count(*)` query gets cached every time when the project loads up. But it didn't work.

Is there a clean hack for caching the `count(*)` query before the first request is made?

Answer (score 0):

Clean Hack? Not really! :)

However, you may play around with a custom class of your own inheriting from `PageNumberPagination`. Then try to reimplement de [`count`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e96320c91724830034033a9cb8afd9cf8c11e2fd/django/core/paginator.py#L92) function on the parent `Paginator` class:

```py
@cached_property
def count(self):
  """Return the total number of objects, across all pages."""
  c = getattr(self.object_list, "count", None)
  if callable(c) and not inspect.isbuiltin(c) and method_has_no_args(c):
    return c()
  return len(self.object_list)
```

Even though that function says `@cached_property` it will create a new instance of `Paginator` class for every request, so, not so much cached.

So, you may implement your own caching solution over this function.

Comment: that didn't help because I already tried to override the count function before and the loading time didn't improve. The first request still took more than 3sec ( db is mysql and table is > 30M records). I need to cache the query before the first request. Is that possible?

Comment: @AbdulRahman. But, in order to cache the results of the query you need to do it at least once, right? Or you mean you want to add it to the cache outside of the request flow?

Comment: Yes I want to create a fake request to that api before user loads that page. Someone suggested me to run a cron job using celery which will make calls at a certain time interval. Maybe that's the only way. Because otherwise I will create a request when the whole django application hasn t been
 loaded.